# FTP restricted user umask - where is it?

Tags: permissions

I've studied this for days and I cannot find the solution.
I have 2 ftp users.
Settings in /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

The shell that this user logs into is /bin/ftponly. The code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "This account is limited to FTP access only."
#!/bin/sh
echo "This account is limited to FTP access only."
```

The user is restricted to an ftp shell and cannot open terminal.

When a user (ex deanhh) uploads a NEW file the permissions are:
`-rw------- 1 deanhh deanhh  118 Jan  3 19:48 testfile`
This looks like umask for the user (deanhh) is 0077 **correct**?

I cannot find where this is being set.
I've looked at:
/etc/vsftpd.conf
/etc/login.defs
/home/deanhh/.bashrc
/home/deanhh/.profile

None of these files set that umask.
Also, the 'home' directory for deanhh is /var/www/deanhh.com not /home/deanhh (which does exist)
There are no files or subfolders in /var/www/deanhh.com to indicate the umask or any user settings.

**How can I determine where umask is being set for ftp users (namely deanhh)?**

Answer (score 2):

You set it in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

In case you are wondering about the current permissions: the `local_umask` setting defaults to `077`, disabling groups and others to access files in any way (as you already noticed).

Several options you can have for user auth:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=0002
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
file_open_mode=0777
```

- `file_open_mode` sets the default setting of files. `777` sets it readable, writeable and executable for anyone. With `local_umask` set to `002`, this gives you `775`.

Comment: THANK YOU     
I couldn't find it because it didn't exist - it was the default.         
I changed it in /etc/vsftpd.conf as you suggested and now it works correctly.

Comment: **@kristy1024** If that works for you don't forget to come back and click the grey check mark below the answer turning it a beautiful green.
**Rinzwind:** <10K and you'll be [#1](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)